# Flash light not working as torch in some android devices

Tags: android, flash

hi everybody i am using nexus 5.I have developed a basic torch app which works in all devices except in nexus 5 please help me

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question like this, it is good to provide relevant information to the problem, such as the code you've tried, error messages you've received, expected outcomes, etc. Just stating a problem with no supporting information to solve that problem is unlikely to get much attention or response.

Answer (score 0):

some devices require surface view to access camara object.

```
    try {
    camera.setPreviewTexture(new SurfaceTexture(0));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Ignore
        }
```